# Spring @transactional behaving strangely with mode=aspectj

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aspectj, transactional

I've been trying to get Spring transactions working properly in my application for days, and now I have nowhere to turn but to the community. Thanks in advance for your help.

My application has specific requirements where I need to annotate a protected overridden method with @Transactional and call this method from the abstract parent class. From what I've read, I can not use proxies, and must use mode=aspectj.

First, some configuration:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="false" mode="aspectj" />

<context:load-time-weaver />

<bean name="ID_DataAccessor" class="dal.DataAccessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost" />
           .....
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
</bean>
```

If I use the @Transactional annotation on a method in ID_DataAccessor, then the connection is transactional (`DataSourceUtils.isConnectionTransactional(c, dataSource) == true`). This is useless to me though, because the transaction commits as soon as the method is completed. When I use @Trasnactional on a method that calls a method in DataAccessor, the connection aquired in DataAccessor (from `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource)`) is NOT transactional. Additionally, I put a breakpoint in DataSourceTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(), and this is only called if the @Transactional annotation is directly on the method acquiring the connection. Forgive me for overloading the terminology, but it appears that the @Transactional annotation does not propagate up the stack.

I'm completely baffled. Please help! :)

Comment: What/where is this other mysterious "method that calls a method in DataAccessor"? What kind of object does it live on, and how is that object created?

Comment: Another bean has a reference to DataAccessor. DataAccessor has methods such as storeThisData(). If the bean referencing DA calls dataAccessor.storeThisData(), the method that this is called from is what I'm referring to.

Comment: How is this other bean created at runtime? Is it in the same ApplicationContext as the DataAccessor or a different one? Is it @Configurable?

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the responses. Both beans are in the same ApplicationContext. An "entry" class with a main method initializes a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and calls "getBean" to get a Processor class. The processor class has a reference to the DataAccess class dependency injected into it. I am trying to make certain methods in the processor transactional. The code is pretty basic - you can take a look at it [here](http://code.google.com/p/packari-autotrade/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FAutoTrade%2Fsrc)

Comment: I really appreciate the help. If you do happen to take a look at the code, you'll be interested in entry.EndOFDayEntryPoint (and AEntryPoint), process.EndOfDayProcessor (and AProcessor), dal.DataAccess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just about gave up on this one. It was quite non-obvious. Your problem is caused by using the `EndOfDayProcess` class [in your entry point](http://code.google.com/p/packari-autotrade/source/browse/trunk/AutoTrade/src/entry/EndOfDayEntryPoint.java). It's a problem because it causes the class to be loaded, and more generally, it'll extend to any of your *Process and *EntryPoint classes. At that point in your code, Spring hasn't been started yet, so its load-time weaver isn't active, and the class gets loaded normally, without the transaction code woven into it. Of course, classes are only loaded once, so it's there to stay, and when you create the bean in Spring, it's a bean whose type doesn't have anything to do with transactions, except it has @Transactional annotations on it. By then, there's nobody there to see them anymore, though. I see two possible (good) solutions:

1. Switch to build-time weaving. Then it's impossible to load a class before it's woven.
2. Change the way you determine which *Process bean to use based on the entry point. Use anything you like except for something that causes the *Process class to be loaded.

Comment: Wow, great analysis. Now you can see why I was getting so frustrated =) Is the way that I am launching processing with the EntryPoint/Process very abnormal? Are there more common patterns for achieving similar behavior?

Comment: It at least shares a common concept with two frameworks I can think of: GWT and JAX-RS. They both have an "entry point" kind of thing that you extend to bootstrap the system. For a standalone process bootstrapping Spring, I couldn't say. I deal mostly with web-related stuff. When I do any kind of standalone Java with Spring (mostly little helper utilities), I pretty much make a main method with one line that creates a context and then do all my work inside Spring. In general--standalone or webapp--I want to be inside the DI container as soon as possible and stay there.